# Replacing string variable with punctuation in R without removing other string

Tags: r, string, replace

In R, I am having trouble replacing a substring that has punctuation. Ie within the string "r.Export", I am trying to replace "r." with "Report.". I've used gsub and below is my code:

```
string <- "r.Export"
short <- "r."
replacement <- "Report."

gsub(short,replacement,string)
```

The desired output is: "Report.Export" however gsub seems to replace the second r such that the output is:

```
Report.ExpoReport.
```

Using sub() instead is not a solution either because I am doing multiple gsubs where sometimes the string to be replaced is:

```
short <- "o."
```

So, then the o's in r.Export are replaced anyway and it becomes a complete mess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string <- "r.Export"
short <- "r\\."
replacement <- "Report."

gsub(short,replacement,string)
```

Returns:

```
[1] "Report.Export"
```

Or, using `fixed=TRUE`:

```
string <- "r.Export"
short <- "r."
replacement <- "Report."

gsub(short,replacement,string, fixed=TRUE)
```

Returns:

```
[1] "Report.Export"
```

Explanation: Without the `fixed=TRUE` argument, `gsub` expects a regular expression as first argument. And with regular expressions `.` is a placeholder for 'any character'. If you want the literal `.` (period) you have to use either `\\.` (i.e. escaping the period) or the aforementioned argument `fixed=TRUE`

Comment: Perfect `fixed=TRUE` is what I was looking for, thanks. I probably should've read the documentation more clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have characters in your pattern (`.`) which has a special meaning in regex use `fixed = TRUE` which matches the string as is.

```
gsub(short,replacement,string, fixed = TRUE)
#[1] "Report.Export"
```

Answer (score 1):

I might actually add word boundaries and lookaheads to the mix here, to ensure as targeted a match as possible:

```
string <- "r.Export"
replacement <- "Report."
output <- gsub("\\br\\.(?=\\w)", replacement, string, perl=TRUE)
output

[1] "Report.Export"
```

This approach ensures that we only match `r.` when the `r` is preceded by whitespace or is the start of the string, and also when what follows the dot is another word.  Consider the sentence `The project r.Export needed a programmer.`  We wouldn't want to replace the final `r.` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `sub`

```
sub(short,replacement,string, fixed = TRUE)
#[1] "Report.Export"
```